# Remove/filter data from item within ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a filter to remove specific string  from data retrieved, for example here `team.teamName` gives back a name such as "FC Arsenal London" or "Sunderland AFC" but if the data given back includes FC, AFC or London then I want that removed, so it only gives back "Arsenal" or "Sunderland" for example. The JSON I access is here:

http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/leagueTable?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teamsList">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>

        <td><a href="#/teams/{{team._links.team.href }}">
              {{team.teamName}}
              </a></td>
        <td>{{team.playedGames}}</td>
        <td>{{team.points}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goals}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalsAgainst}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalDifference}}</td>
      </tr>
```

CONTROLLER.js

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp.controllers', []).
  controller('teamsController', function($scope, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.teamsList = [];

    footballdataAPIservice.getTeams().success(function (response) {
        //Dig into the response to get the relevant data
        $scope.teamsList = response.standing;
    });
  });
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: $scope.teamName = function(url) {
     return url.replace(/London?/AFC?/FC, '');
 };    tried this but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an AngularJS [filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/tutorial/step_09) that removes the 'AFC' and 'FC'.

Here's an example:

```
.filter('removeteam', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.replace('AFC', '').replace('FC', '');
    }
});
```

Which you call through by piping some field into the filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="team in teams">{{ team.name | removeteam }}</li>
```

Here's a fiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/cuyw8a4b/1/